# Parse json to html with table format

Tags: json, xml

I have parsed coding(data) from XML to JSON. The parsed JSON value should be displayed on html page with table format.

I have two questions:

1. How to get the parsed values??
2. How to display parsed values to html?

Comment: easily to handle using `jquery`

Comment: depends on what you prefer to code with, you can proceed with jquery or unobtrusive javascript as well